# 4s4p Li-Ion battery pack charging

Tags: batteries, bluetooth, lithium-ion, charge

I've made a 16 cell battery with Li-ion 18650's salvaged from laptops in a 4s4p configuration at around 16.4V. I'm using it in a Bluetooth speaker I made with a TDA7492 Bluetooth audio board, and am using [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/182095503401?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) 18650 protection circuit. 
I was wondering if I needed a 16V power supply and connect the charge port straight to the protection board, or if I need something like a TP4056 micro usb, but made for 16V.

I'm still new to all this and am taking every chance I can get to learn more about DC voltage. So any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please draw a block diagram of your setup. Please also write a specific question. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A more specific question (along the lines of 'here is my circuit, and everything I've considered - is 'x' correct') will get a much better answer. You probably do need something to switch off charging at a specific voltage though.

Answer (score 1):

A 16V power supply will be insufficient for your build. You need at least 17V supplied under load.

You could use a notebook charger rated at 19.5V. The protection circuit will handle the limitations, but you have to make sure that the charger can supply sufficient current for the whole pack. At 4 parallel cells, you'd need at least 4A supplied current (and use a charging at 1C).

Other than that, para-series charge is not generally recommended because a single bad cell over time will discharge the pair, which will not fully charge, which will end up with a bad pack consisting of 1 bad pair, 2 relatively good ones and 1 very good one.